# How can I correct my PHP code for this SQL query?

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

I've been messing with this for a while and I'm nearly there. Just need to get past this wall I've hit.

I have the following tables:

```
tracks (trackid, tracktitle, albumid, composerid)
albums (albumid, albumname)
composers (composerid, composername)
```

I can insert a new record via PhpMyAdmin SQL tab with

```
INSERT INTO tracks (tracktitle, albumid, composerid) VALUES ('New Song', 1, 1);
```

and it works fine.

My PHP form though isn't doing the same thing and I must have overlooked something. 
Please can someone check out the code for my addtrack page and tell me what is wrong?

```
 if (isset($_POST['tracktitle'])): 
 // A new track has been entered
 // using the form.

 $cid= $_POST['cid'];
 $tracktitle = $_POST['tracktitle'];
 $albs = $_POST['albs'];

 if ($cid == '') {
 exit('<p>You must choose an composer for this track. 
 Click "Back" and try again.</p>');
  }

  $sql = "INSERT INTO tracks SET
  tracks.tracktitle='$tracktitle'" ;
  if (@mysql_query($sql)) {
  echo '<p>New track added</p>';
  } else {
  exit('<p>Error adding new track' . mysql_error() . '</p>');
  }

  $trackid = mysql_insert_id();

  if (isset($_POST['albs'])) {
   $albs = $_POST['albs'];
   } else {
   $albs = array();
   }

  $numAlbs = 0;
  foreach ($albs as $albID) {
  $sql = "INSERT IGNORE INTO tracks (trackid, albumid, 
  composerid) VALUES " . 
"($trackid, $albs, $cid)";

if ($ok) {
  $numAlbs = $numAlbs + 1;
} else {
  echo "<p>Error inserting track into album $albID: " .
      mysql_error() . '</p>';
}
}
 ?>

<p>Track was added to <?php echo $numAlbs; ?> albums.</p>

 <p><a href="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>">Add another 
 track</a></p>
 <p><a href="tracks.php">Return to track search</a></p>

 <?php
 else: // Allow the user to enter a new track

 $composers = @mysql_query('SELECT composerid, composername 
 FROM composers');
  if (!$composers) {
 exit('<p>Unable to obtain composer list from the 
database.</p>');
 }

$albs = @mysql_query('SELECT albumid, albumname FROM albums');
 if (!$albs) {
 exit('<p>Unable to obtain album list from the 
 database.</p>');
 }
 ?>

 <form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" 
 method="post">
 <p>Enter the new track:<br />
 <textarea name="tracktitle" rows="1" cols="20">
 </textarea></p>
 <p>Composer:
 <select name="cid" size="1">
  <option selected value="">Select One</option>
  <option value="">---------</option> 
  <?php
   while ($composer= mysql_fetch_array($composers)) {
    $cid = $composer['composerid'];
    $cname = htmlspecialchars($composer['composername']);
    echo "<option value='$cid'>$cname</option>\n";
     }
    ?>
    </select></p>
    <p>Place in albums:<br />
   <?php
   while ($alb = mysql_fetch_array($albs)) {
    $aid = $alb['albumid'];
    $aname = htmlspecialchars($alb['albumname']);
     echo "<label><input type='checkbox' name='albs[]'
    value='$aid' />$aname</label><br />\n";
    }
   ?>
```

Once I have this sorted, I can move on to expanding it and also sorting out the security issues. Someone on here recommended I look into PDO's which are a new thing to me. 
But one hurdle at a time....

Thanks

Comment: Do you get an error message, and if so, what does it say? - EDIT: Actually, I see the problem now.

Comment: You're also missing an `endif;` at the very end (the opening `if:` is never closed).

Comment: Which DBMS are you using, out of curiosity?

Comment: Thanks for all the help. yc I do have an endif but didn't include it in the above. I just quoted the main chunk of php code. Helgi, I'm using PHPMyAdmin. I've amended the INSERT INTO/SET code to what I should have done (and in fact what I had already done in another section - obviously overlooked it) but I'm getting the error message "Error adding new trackCannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`musicsearch`.`tracks`, CONSTRAINT `tracks_ibfk_4` FOREIGN KEY (`albumid`) REFERENCES `albums` (`albumid`) ON DELETE CASCADE)".

Comment: My Relation View in MyPhpAdmin looks like this...              trackid                         
albumid 'musicsearch', 'albums', 'albumid' ON DELETE cascade ON UPDATE  
composerid 'musicsearch', 'composers', 'composerid' ON DELETE cascade ON UPDATE  
tracktitle No index defined!  I guess I've missed something out along the way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your INSERT syntax is incorrect. You are trying to INSERT using an UPDATE syntax.

You are trying:

```
INSERT INTO table_name SET field_name = '$value', another_field_name = '$another_value'
```

But you should be doing:

```
INSERT INTO table_name (
    field_name,
    another_field_name
)
VALUES (
    '$value',
    '$another_value'
)
```

Also, you really should be using addslahes(), like this:

```
INSERT INTO table_name (
    field_name,
    another_field_name
)
VALUES (
    '".addslashes($value)."',
    '".addslashes($another_value)."'
)
```

Otherwise your code is easier to hack than a boiled potato. :)

EDIT: Chad Birch (below) suggests rather using parameterized values, which admittedly is better than addslashes(). I honestly didn't know PHP had those already.

Comment: `INSERT INTO table_name SET field_name = 'foo', another_field_name = 'bar'` is perfectly valid in MySQL.

Comment: Well, I'll be damned! It works on my MySQL installation but not MS-SQL. Surely it's not standard SQL though?

Comment: `addslashes()` is not a good protection either. Look into parameterized queries, which are usually done through the Mysqli or PDO functions.

Comment: @Helgi - no, it's not valid SQL, it only works in MySQL, and as such it's a terrible idea.  You should amend your answer to state that, while valid in MySQL, the syntax should be avoided because it's not portable.

Comment: Yes I've not tackled the security side of things just yet. I want to get my head around getting this thing working. PDO is totally new to me so I'll be reading up on it. I've amended the code as mentioned above but getting a new error message.

Answer (score 0):

The problems are in your queries. Try using mysql_error function to get extra information on what you are doing wrong.

As an example your INSERT statement is malformed.

You have:

```
$sql="INSERT INTO tracks SET tracks.tracktitle='$tracktitle'"
```

It should be something like:

```
$sql="INSERT INTO tracks (tracktitle) VALUES ('$tracktitle')";
```

Comment: Thanks Wifi, I'd already amended this in another section of code but obviously missed it out for this bit. Obviously didn't realise the difference. Learning all the time....

Comment: Still having problems though as detailed the first batch of comments. Can't work it out..

Answer (score 0):

My previous answer was wrong (and is deleted). I've learned now that your Insert syntax is indeed valid.

But what you don't do, is escape the value you put in the query. If $tracktitle contains any invalid characters, like a single quote, it could break your query.

You should add this line before building your insert query:

```
$tracktitle = mysql_real_escape_string($tracktitle);
```

You current code is *very* dangarous. If I was to insert a song, and in the song name I would type *YourF...ed, oh by the way'; drop database YourDataBaseName;* you should try to imagine what happens..

This is known as SQL-injection. Because you don't correctly escape the value, someone else can close the statment en start a new statement by just inserting it into a html form field.

I don't know if this is the reason that your query doesn't work right now (it only breaks if you type an invalid character), but it is a serious problem at the moment.

To find out your exact error, you should display the results of mysql_error() when mysql_query() returns false. This will probably help you more than any random guesses we can make here.

Comment: Thank you. I shall delve further and read up on PDO's and stuff.